# Converting OpenCV2 image into Kivy Texture

Tags: python, opencv, kivy

I'm currently trying to take frames from a video (using openCV2) and then display them in an app using Kivy.

due to the differing image formats, I've had to resort to saving the image from openCV2 to disk and then reading it in Kivy, which is an inelegant solution and occasionally causes crashes (where the Kivy section tries to access the image before it's finished saving fully)

I'm trying to pass the image directly, with no disc access involved. currently, I'm attempting to save the image from openCV2 into a buffer using cv2.imencode, and then converting the buffer into a kivy texture using Texture.blit_buffer

at the moment, the image extraction looks like:

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(videourl)
success, image = video.read()
success2, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
```

while the texture creation looks like:

```
tex = Texture.create()
tex.blit_buffer(buffer, colorfmt='rgb', bufferfmt='ubyte')
```

however, I've been getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)
```

from this, I'm guessing that it's expecting the array to be 1 dimensional. do I just need to convert the openCV2 image (which is stored as a numpy n-dimensional array) to a single dimensional array? and if so, what else would I need to do to make sure the image copies over correctly?

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flatten your buffer by

```
buffer.flatten()
```

and it should work.